# Differential Equations and Unit Notation

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, units

1. What do I get the `Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed .` error when I try to use the math palette for derivatives?
2. What does the dot in `10. Farad Micro Volt mean`? Multiplication?
3. [image] Why is my `C1` changed to `C[1]`? What does that mean? Basically I wanted to use `C` for capacitance but the letter `C` was protected.
4. How come my unit convert isn't working? What's the easiest way to get my final result in units? [wolframalpha.com](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) often will figure out what units you want but only allows you enter one line so I'm trying to learn *Mathematica*

   ```
   R := 500 Ohm 
   C1 := 0.5 Micro Farad 
   V := 20 Volt
   DSolve[R*q1'[t] + 1/C1*q1[t] == V, q1[t], t]
   (* {{q1[t] -> 10. Farad Micro Volt + E^(-((0.004 t)/(Farad Micro Ohm))) C[1]}} *)

   TraditionalForm[R*q1'[t] + 1/C1*q1[t] == V]
   (* (2. q1(t))/(Farad Micro)+500 Ohm q1^′(t)==20 Volt *)

   R := 500 Ohm 
   C1 := 0.5 Micro Farad 
   V := 20 Volt
   DSolve[R*(\[DifferentialD]/\[DifferentialD]t)q1[t] + 1/C1*q1[t] == V, q1[t], t]

   (* During evaluation of In[89]:= Syntax::sntxi: Incomplete expression; more input is needed . *)

   UnitConvert[10.` Farad Micro Volt + E^(-((0.004` t)/(Farad Micro Ohm))) C[1], Coulomb]
   (* UnitConvert[10. Farad Micro Volt + E^(-((0.004 t)/(Farad Micro Ohm))) C[1], Coulomb] *)
   ```

Comment: 2) `10.` is an inexact number. A real. 3) Just coincidence. `C[1]` is a default unknown variable. see the docs for the option `GeneratedParameters`.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think units are going to work with this calculation.

I couldn't find any way to give `t` a dimension of time that would be accepted by `DSolve`, although [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/NumericalCalculationsWithUnits.html) seems to suggest that it isn't necessary. This leads us to the following:

```
r = Quantity[500, "Ohms"];
c = Quantity[0.5, "Microfarads"];
v = Quantity[20 , "Volts"];
DSolve[{
   r*Quantity[q1'[t], "Coulombs"/"Seconds"] +
    1/c*Quantity[q1[t], "Coulombs"] == v
  }, q1[t], t
 ]
```

[image: failed DSolve output with Solve::units messages]

Clearly, `DSolve` failed. It makes no difference if you use `"Amperes"` instead of `"Coulombs"/"Seconds"`. I tried a number of other potentially acceptable ways of stating the input, but they seemed to confuse `DSolve` even more and none of them produced any better result than this.

`NDSolve` doesn't produce an output with units and won't accept `q1[0] == Quantity[0, "Coulombs"]` as an initial condition. But note that it did not complain about units being present in the input and the time-scaling of the result **is** correct for the unit of *micro*farads, so clearly it did something correctly with units:

```
r = Quantity[500, "Ohms"];
c = Quantity[0.5, "Microfarads"];
v = Quantity[20 , "Volts"];
sol = NDSolveValue[{
   r*Quantity[q1'[t], "Coulombs"/"Seconds"] +
    1/c*Quantity[q1[t], "Coulombs"] == v,
   q1[0] == 0
  }, q1[t], {t, 0, 1*^-3}
 ];
Plot[q1[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 1*^-3}]
```

[image: Plot of NDSolve output for capacitor charging]

You could use `ParametricNDSolve`(`Value`) to parameterize the initial charge.

The most successful approach is just `DSolve` without any attempt to use units:

```
r = 500;
c = 0.5*^-6;
v = 20;
sol = DSolve[{r*q1'[t] + 1/c*q1[t] == v, q1[0] == x}, q1[t], t]
(* -> {{q1[t] -> 0.00001 E^(-4000. t) (-1. + 1. E^(4000. t) + 100000. x)}} *)

Plot[q1[t] /. sol /. x -> 0, {t, 0, 1*^-3}]
```

[image: Plot of DSolve output without units for capacitor charging]

Units have not been part of *Mathematica* for very long and this frustrating experience does not seem to be unusual for people attempting to work with them. To avoid such things, my suggestion would be to do the value and units calculations separately.